# How can we SELECT one or more Cosmos documents using Postman?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, postman-pre-request-script

Out of morbid curiosity, how can a document be retrieved by directly exercising the Cosmos REST API? For my use case I would like to see it done within Postman.

Answer (score 1):

Morbid is correct.

1. Url is in the form `https://{{cosmosUrlName}}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{{cosmosDbName}}/colls/{{cosmosCollectionName}}/docs`.
2. Replace `cosmosUrlName` with the name of the Cosmos instance, I.E. `cosmos-db-name-here`.
3. Replace `cosmosDbName` with the name of the Cosmos database, I.E. `AccountDb`.
4. Replace `cosmosCollectionName` with the name of the Cosmos container for that database, I.E. `accounts`.
5. Ensure the payload is a JSON query that adheres to a structure like this: `{ "query": "...", "parameters": [...] }` (reference the example below).
6. Add header `x-ms-date` set to the current date and time, conforming to the standard for HTTP dates (I.E. `Tue, 28 Feb 2023 08:12:31 GMT`). See the code example below.
7. Add header `x-ms-version` and set it to `2018-12-31`.
8. Add header `x-ms-documentdb-isquery` and set it to `True`.
9. Add header `x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition` and set it to `True`.
10. Override header `Content-Type`, setting it to `application/query+json` otherwise you may get complaints about partition keys.
11. The fun part: Add an `Authorization` header whose value is `type=master&ver=1.0&sig={sig}`, where `{sig}` is the result of a HMAC SHA256 hashing operation against a multi-line string in the format `{verb}\n{resourceType}\n{resourceLink}\n{date}\n\n` using the not-base64-encoded version of the Cosmos primary or secondary key, as per the article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources
12. Good luck. If anything goes wrong keep trying and hope you get it right soon!

The following sections provide a clean example on how to do this in Postman, to get a specific document from the `AccountDb.accounts` container in the dev environment:

#### URL Example

- HTTP **POST** `https://cosmos-db-name-here.documents.azure.com/dbs/AccountDb/colls/accounts/docs`

#### Payload Example

```json
{  
    "query": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.email = 'someone@example.com'",
    "parameters": []  
}
```

#### Pre-request Script Example

```js
let moment = require('moment');
let date = moment().format("ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + " GMT"; // We use GMT but others can be used

pm.request.headers.add({ key: 'x-ms-date', value: date });
pm.request.headers.add({ key: 'x-ms-version', value: '2018-12-31' });
pm.request.headers.add({ key: 'x-ms-documentdb-isquery', value: 'True' });
pm.request.headers.add({ key: 'x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition', value: 'True' });
pm.request.headers.add({ key: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/query+json' });

let verb = "post";
let resourceType = "docs";
let resourceLink = "dbs/AccountDb/colls/accounts";
let payload = verb + '\n' + resourceType + '\n' + resourceLink + '\n' + date.toLowerCase() + '\n\n';

let masterKey = pm.collectionVariables.get('cosmosDbMasterKey');
let decodedMasterKey = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(masterKey);
let hashed = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(payload, decodedMasterKey);
let sig = hashed.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

let headerValue = encodeURIComponent('type=master&ver=1.0&sig=' + sig);
pm.request.headers.add({ key: 'Authorization', value: headerValue });
```